# Flutter: Unable to Migrate to AndroidX

Tags: flutter, androidx

I was trying to import my flutter app into Android Studio to migrate to Androidx, not sure if these are the correct steps:

1. FlutterProject > Open the Android module in Android Studio.
2. My Android version is 3.2.0+, able to do Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

While trying to migrate to Androidx, I received an `Unresolved Dependecies` error stating that:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.1.1
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app

I couldn't find out where is this `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.1.1` located. I've tried implementing the Androidx build artifact, not working at all.

Comment: have you added maven to your repository's build.gradle?

Comment: Yes I did. It still didn't work, this ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:27.1.1 keep showing. I'm avoiding AndroidX for now by removing ^ from each plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to migrate flutter project to support AndroidX without having to use Android studio.

Here's what I did..

1. updated `compileSdkVersion` in build.gradle file to `28`
2. `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in `gradle.properties`

Try this approach if all you want to do is migrate to AndroidX